# How to split a comma separated String while ignoring escaped commas?

Tags: java, regex, csv

I need to write a extended version of the StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray function which gets an additional parameter: the escape char.

so calling my:

```
commaDelimitedListToStringArray("test,test\\,test\\,test,test", "\\")
```

should return:

```
["test", "test,test,test", "test"]
```

My current attempt is to use String.split() to split the String using regular expressions:

```
String[] array = str.split("[^\\\\],");
```

But the returned array is:

```
["tes", "test\,test\,tes", "test"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The regular expression

```
[^\\],
```

means "match a character which is not a backslash followed by a comma" - this is why patterns such as `t,` are matching, because `t` is a character which is not a backslash.

I think you need to use some sort of [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), to capture a `,` which is not preceded by a `\` without capturing the preceding character, something like

```
(?<!\\),
```

(BTW, note that I have purposefully not doubly-escaped the backslashes to make this more readable)

Comment: This again will incorrecty split a string like "test\\,tost" (also intentionally not doubly escaped), which should have been split up as "test\\" and "tost". To overcome this, I once found this (Java) regex: "(?<=(?<!\\\)(\\\\\){0,100})," which still is not perfect (and still needs to be doubly escaped, i.e. "(?<=(?<!\\\\\)(\\\\\\\\\){0,100})," ). But it'll do

Comment: While this works, it does not yield the desired result. It backslash is retained.

Answer (score 33):

Try:

```
String array[] = str.split("(?<!\\\\),");
```

Basically this is saying split on a comma, except where that comma is preceded by two backslashes. This is called a [negative lookbehind zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: that works quite well ... thank you

result is:

["test", "test\,test\,test", "test"]

Comment: Actually, it matches a comma preceded by ONE backslash. In a regex written as a Java String literal, it takes FOUR backslashes to match ONE in the target text.

Comment: If you wanna remove the slashes too, use this:

    Arrays.stream(text.split("(?<!\\\\)\\s", -1))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\", "")).collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, here is the complete method i ended up with:

```
public static String[] commaDelimitedListToStringArray(String str, String escapeChar) {
    // these characters need to be escaped in a regular expression
    String regularExpressionSpecialChars = "/.*+?|()[]{}\\";

    String escapedEscapeChar = escapeChar;

    // if the escape char for our comma separated list needs to be escaped 
    // for the regular expression, escape it using the \ char
    if(regularExpressionSpecialChars.indexOf(escapeChar) != -1) 
        escapedEscapeChar = "\\" + escapeChar;

    // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820172/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-while-ignoring-escaped-commas
    String[] temp = str.split("(?<!" + escapedEscapeChar + "),", -1);

    // remove the escapeChar for the end result
    String[] result = new String[temp.length];
    for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
        result[i] = temp[i].replaceAll(escapedEscapeChar + ",", ",");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Escaping doesn't need to be that difficult:  

String[] temp = str.split("(?<!\\Q" + escapeChar + "\\E),", -1);

Comment: @AlanMoore You can also use the `Pattern.quote()` method to "escape" a string for safe inclusion in a regular expression.  The method wraps the string in `\Q` and `\E`.

Comment: @Michael: That's true, and as a bonus it escapes any literal `\E` sequence in the original so it doesn't get treated as an ending delimiter.  I never liked the `\Q..\E` feature in Perl, and I like it even less in Java, but that's no excuse for handing out bad advice about it.  Cheers!

Comment: @AlanMoore I think using `\Q..\E` (whether it be hard-coded or through `Pattern.quote()`) is better than defining a list of special characters and adding a backslash if the given character is in the list.

Answer (score 2):

As matt b said, `[^\\],` will interpret the character preceding the comma as a part of the delimiter.

```
"test\\\\\\,test\\\\,test\\,test,test"
  -(split)->
["test\\\\\\,test\\\\,test\\,tes" , "test"]
```

As drvdijk said, `(?<!\\),` will misinterpret escaped backslashes.

```
"test\\\\\\,test\\\\,test\\,test,test"
  -(split)->
["test\\\\\\,test\\\\,test\\,test" , "test"]
  -(unescape commas)->
["test\\\\,test\\,test,test" , "test"]
```

I would expect being able to escape backslashes as well...

```
"test\\\\\\,test\\\\,test\\,test,test"
  -(split)->
["test\\\\\\,test\\\\" , "test\\,test" , "test"]
  -(unescape commas and backslashes)->
["test\\,test\\" , "test,test" , "test"]
```

drvdijk suggested `(?<=(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\){0,100}),` which works well for lists with elements ending with up to 100 backslashes. This is far enough... but why a limit? Is there a more efficient way (isn't lookbehind greedy)? What about invalid strings?

I searched for a while for a generic solution, then I wrote the thing myself... The idea is to split following a pattern that matches the list elements (instead of matching the delimiter).

My answer does not take the escape character as a parameter.

```
public static List<String> commaDelimitedListStringToStringList(String list) {
    // Check the validity of the list
    // ex: "te\\st" is not valid, backslash should be escaped
    if (!list.matches("^(([^\\\\,]|\\\\,|\\\\\\\\)*(,|$))+")) {
        // Could also raise an exception
        return null;
    }
    // Matcher for the list elements
    Matcher matcher = Pattern
            .compile("(?<=(^|,))([^\\\\,]|\\\\,|\\\\\\\\)*(?=(,|$))")
            .matcher(list);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Unescape the list element
        result.add(matcher.group().replaceAll("\\\\([\\\\,])", "$1"));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Description for the pattern (unescaped):

`(?<=(^|,))` forward is start of string or a `,`

`([^\\,]|\\,|\\\\)*` the element composed of `\,`, `\\` or characters wich are neither `\` nor `,`

`(?=(,|$))` behind is end of string or a `,`

The pattern may be simplified.

Even with the 3 parsings (`matches` + `find` + `replaceAll`), this method seems faster than the one suggested by drvdijk. It can still be optimized by writing a specific parser.

Also, what is the need of having an escape character if only one character is special, it could simply be doubled...

```
public static List<String> commaDelimitedListStringToStringList2(String list) {
    if (!list.matches("^(([^,]|,,)*(,|$))+")) {
        return null;
    }
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(^|,))([^,]|,,)*(?=(,|$))")
                    .matcher(list);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(matcher.group().replaceAll(",,", ","));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`split(/(?<!\\),/g)` worked for me, but the accepted answer did not

```
> var x = "test,test\,test\,test,test"
undefined
> x.split(/(?<!\\),/g)
[ 'test', 'test\\,test\\,test', 'test' ]
> x.split("(?<!\\\\),")
[ 'test,test\\,test\\,test,test' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not "super fancy" solution, but possibly more time-efficient one. Escaping an escape character is also supported and it's working in [browsers not supporting 'lookbehinds'](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

```js
function splitByDelimiterIfItIsNotEscaped (text, delimiter, escapeCharacter) {
    const splittedText = []
    let numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter = 0
    let nextSplittedTextPartIndex = 0
    for (let characterIndex = 0, character = text[0]; characterIndex < text.length; characterIndex++, character = text[characterIndex]) {
        if (character === escapeCharacter) {
            numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter++
        } else if (character === delimiter && (!numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter || !(numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter % 2))) {
            splittedText.push(text.substring(nextSplittedTextPartIndex, characterIndex))
            nextSplittedTextPartIndex = characterIndex + 1
        } else {
            numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter = 0
        }
    }
    if (nextSplittedTextPartIndex <= text.length) {
        splittedText.push(text.substring(nextSplittedTextPartIndex, text.length))
    }
    return splittedText
}

function onChange () {
    console.log(splitByDelimiterIfItIsNotEscaped(inputBox.value, ',', '\\'))
}

addEventListener('change', onChange)

onChange()
```

```html
After making a change unfocus the input box (use tab for example).
<input id="inputBox" value="test,test\,test\,test,test"/>
```