# JavaScript split on char but ignoring double escaped chars

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something similar to this but cant get it working.

[How to split a comma separated String while ignoring escaped commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820172/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-while-ignoring-escaped-commas.)

I have tried to figure it out but cant seem to get it right.

I would like to split the string on `:` but not the escaped one `\\:`
(my escape char is a double slash)

given: `dtet:du\\,eduh ei\\:di:e,j`
expected outcome: `["dtet"] ["du\\,eduh ei\\:di][e,j"]`

regex link:
https://regex101.com/r/12j6er/1/

Comment: this `(?!\\\\:):` is close but still can not get it working

Comment: Are you sure that the input string contains two backslashes, or is it just the string literal that has escaped one backslash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the function below named `splitOnNonEscapedDelimeter()`, which accepts the `string` to split, and the `delimeter` to split on, which in this case is `:`. The usage is within the function `onChange()`.

> Note that you must escape the `delimeter` you pass to `splitOnNonEscapedDelimeter()`, so that it is not interpreted as a [special character in the regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions).

```js
function nonEscapedDelimeter(delimeter) {
  return new RegExp(String.raw`[^${delimeter}]*?(?:\\\\${delimeter}[^${delimeter}]*?)*(?:${delimeter}|$)`, 'g')
}

function nonEscapedDelimeterAtEnd(delimeter) {
  return new RegExp(String.raw`([^\\].|.[^\\]|^.?)${delimeter}$`)
}

function splitOnNonEscapedDelimeter(string, delimeter) {
  const reMatch = nonEscapedDelimeter(delimeter)
  const reReplace = nonEscapedDelimeterAtEnd(delimeter)

  return string.match(reMatch).slice(0, -1).map(section => {
    return section.replace(reReplace, '$1')
  })
}

function onChange() {
  console.log(splitOnNonEscapedDelimeter(i.value, ':'))
}

i.addEventListener('change', onChange)

onChange()
```

```html
<textarea id=i>dtet:du\\,eduh ei\\:di:e,j</textarea>
```

#### Requirements

This solution makes use of the ES2015 features [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for convenience, though these are not required. See the relevant documentation above to understand how these work and use [a polyfill such as this](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=true&spec=true&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGBBRAzhAhgBwKYAmAIngDYwC2eUeATgBQFmXV0CUiA3gFCKK3UQtJGDwB3RACU8Ac1QAPHPQDKUWjDAyAdLSxiABgG0AegBJOTclRq0AvgF0AVAH56zgFwAdb5_OWWNrYmfszWdA4ubI5u7iFWrHYAPqZs-gA0iADkMpls3Lbc3KCQsAjIaJi4hCTxNgCCUKhgBIyhCRw8fAJQQiLiUrIKSqrqmjp6-vQm3vZaiVrTnvaJxlrObHEB4ab6eQVF4NDwSOg45FAA8mAAchXY-MRtNvToahoyGf5htB28iBAIV78PAAWSwUAgAAtEABecpgDD3apPOitWrsP4AsBAgTSM5YCB4WHwxFVR7o2gNJotL7tQpdQTCRCvUbaCjgqH0ARgiGQthadDkQn0AAMGQAtABGfnspToPBHMowgB8XD-DJ6TPlirAOjw-OFuP1pAJeAymVMktyf1seyAA) if your target platform does not include support for these features.

#### Explanation

```
new RegExp(String.raw`[^${delimeter}]*?(?:\\\\${delimeter}[^${delimeter}]*?)*(?:${delimeter}|$)`, 'g')
```

The function `nonEscapedDelimeter()` creates a regular expression that does almost what is required, except with a few quirks that need to be corrected with some post-processing.

```
string.match(reMatch)
```

The regular expression, when used in [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), splits the string into sections that either end with the non-escaped `delimeter`, or to the end of the string. This also has the side-effect of matching a 0-width section at the end of the string, thus we need to

```
.slice(0, -1)
```

to remove that match in post-processing.

```
new RegExp(String.raw`([^\\].|.[^\\]|^.?)${delimeter}$`)

...

.map(section => {
  return section.replace(reReplace, '')
})
```

Since each section now ends with the `delimeter` except for the last one (which ends at the end of the string), we need to [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array of matches and remove the *non-escaped* `delimeter` (thus why `nonEscapedDelimeterAtEnd()` is so complicated), if it is there.

Comment: Interesting approach :) small sidenote: It's `delimiter`, not `delimeter` (stems from limit, not meter, I guess) -- seems to be a common spelling error.

Comment: @Jay my bad. thank you for pointing that out, I suppose I should fix that at some point.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit lengthy approach. but works for you. JavaScript regular expressions do not support lookbehinds. But you can do it by simply reverse your original string and split a string using lookahead. And then reverse array and all strings in it and you will get your result.

```js
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}


var str = "dtet:du\\,eduh ei\\:di:e,j";
var res = reverse(str);
var result  = res.split(/:(?!\\)/g);
result  = result.reverse();
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
 result[i] = reverse(result[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you can use split("").reverse().join("") to reverse a string :D (see Bonus Solution in my answer)

Comment: Thank you, would this work if i replaced `:` with with whatever wanted  the delimiter to be based on the double escape.

Comment: why is it that when i run this i am only getting one slash and instead of 2, works as expected in SO... but in console does not. P.S. the Split i right but its dropping a escape char

Comment: backslash(\) character is treated as an escape character in javascript, so javascript ignores it and prints next character as a control symbol. Use console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) to print the string with \\.

Answer (score 2):

I could come up with two solutions. One that is based on adjusting array contents and one that uses a regex.

**Solution 1:**

Approach: Split on `:`, then shovel elements into new array and glue those back together that should **not** have been split.

```
function splitcolon(input) {
    var inparts = input.split(":");
    var outparts = [];
    var splitwaslegit = true;
    inparts.forEach(function(part) {
        if (splitwaslegit) {
            outparts.push(part);
        } else { // the split was not justified, so reverse it by gluing this part to the previous one
            outparts[outparts.length-1] += ":" + part;
        }
        // the next split was legit if this part doesn't end on \\
        splitwaslegit = (part.substring(part.length-2) !== "\\\\");
    });
    return outparts;
}
```

Tested in chrome:

```
splitcolon("dtet:du\\\\,eduh ei\\\\:di:e,j")
(3) ["dtet", "du\\,eduh ei\\:di", "e,j"]
```

Note:
Could of course also use a `for` loop or underscore's `each` instead of `forEach`

**Solution 2:**

Approach: If there is any char or string of which you can be 100% sure that it won't be in the input, then you can use that char/string as a temporary delimiter inserted by a regex like this:

```
var tmpdelim = "\x00"; // must *never* ever occur in input string

var input = "dtet:du\\\\,eduh ei\\\\:di:e,j";
input.replace(/(^.?|[^\\].|.[^\\]):/g, "$1" + tmpdelim).split(tmpdelim);
```

Result:

```
(3) ["dtet", "du\\,eduh ei\\:di", "e,j"]
```

Explanation of regular expression `/(^.?|[^\\].|.[^\\]):/g`:

`/` - start of regex
`(` - *matching group 1* start
`^.?` - we're at input start or any single char away from it (the escape requires 2)
`|` - or
`[^\\].` - any char that is not a `\` followed by any other char
`|` - or
`.[^\\]` - any char followed by anything other than a `\`
`)` - *matching group 1* stop
`:` - the matching group (which can't be `\\`) must be followed by a `:`
`/` - end of regex
`g` - regex modifier *global* (match *all* occurances, not just the first)

which we replace with `$1 + tmpdelim`, so with whatever was in *matching group 1*, followed by our special delimiter (instead of `:`) which we can then use for splitting.

**Bonus solution**

Manjo Verma's answer as one-liner:

```
input.split("").reverse().join("").split(/:(?!\\\\)/).reverse().map(x => x.split("").reverse().join(""));
```

Result:

```
(3) ["dtet", "du\\,eduh ei\\:di", "e,j"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the one-liner's regexp contain the `g` flag?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was wondering that too, for a moment. But split() uses the provided delimiter parameter (in this case a regex) for splitting as often as possible, so the `g` is already implied :)

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not "super fancy" solution, but possibly more time-efficient one. Escaping an escape character is also supported and it's working in [browsers not supporting 'lookbehinds'](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

```js
function splitByDelimiterIfItIsNotEscaped (text, delimiter, escapeCharacter) {
    const splittedText = []
    let numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter = 0
    let nextSplittedTextPartIndex = 0
    for (let characterIndex = 0, character = text[0]; characterIndex < text.length; characterIndex++, character = text[characterIndex]) {
        if (character === escapeCharacter) {
            numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter++
        } else if (character === delimiter && (!numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter || !(numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter % 2))) {
            splittedText.push(text.substring(nextSplittedTextPartIndex, characterIndex))
            nextSplittedTextPartIndex = characterIndex + 1
        } else {
            numberOfDelimitersBeforeOtherCharacter = 0
        }
    }
    if (nextSplittedTextPartIndex <= text.length) {
        splittedText.push(text.substring(nextSplittedTextPartIndex, text.length))
    }
    return splittedText
}

function onChange () {
    console.log(splitByDelimiterIfItIsNotEscaped(inputBox.value, ':', '\\'))
}

addEventListener('change', onChange)

onChange()
```

```html
After making a change unfocus the input box (use tab for example).
<input id="inputBox" value="dtet:du\,eduh ei\:di:e,j"/>
```