# Neo4j LOAD CSV process arrays in CSV documents using a separator

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, load-csv

I'm using `LOAD CSV` to import data from `csv` to `neo4j`. My dataset contains multiple values in the `country` field. Currently I'm using a semicolon as the separator of those multiple values.

***nodes-person.csv***

```
id,country
http://author,country1;country2;country3
```

And this is the cypher query which I use to import data into `neo4j`

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes-person.csv" AS csvLine
  MERGE (p:`person` {id: csvLine.id})
    ON CREATE
    SET
    p.country = split(csvLine.country,";")

    ON MATCH
    SET
    p.country = split(csvLine.country,";")

RETURN p;
```

My question is, how can I split the values properly if the values contain the separator character.

ie:

```
country\\;1 ; country\\;2 ; country\\;3
```

Comment: You only need a single slash unless you are escaping the slash character as well, so `country\;1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of options - one is pure Cypher and slightly untidy, the other is using APOC and regular expressions. I'm making the assumption that if the semicolon appears within a country name it's escaped with a single backslash.

### Cypher route

The plan here is to do three replacements:

- Replace instances of the escaped semicolon with some string that's very unlikely to appear as a country name (say, `__SEMICOLON__`)
- Split the string by semicolons as you're doing so far
- Within each string resulting from the split, replace `__SEMICOLON__` instances with a semicolon character

Something like the following would work (the `WITH` is just so it's runnable in isolation):

```
WITH 'country1\\;;country2;country3\\;' as countries
RETURN [x in split(replace(countries, '\\;', '__SEMICOLON__'), ';') | replace(x, '__SEMICOLON__', ';')]
```

[image]

### APOC and Regular Expressions

A tidier approach is to use `apoc.text.replace` and supply a regular expression as the 'separator', where we want to split the string by semicolons that are not preceded by the backslash escape character:

```
WITH 'country1\\;;country2;country3\\;' as countries
RETURN [x in apoc.text.split(countries, '(?<!\\\\);') | replace(x, '\\;', ';')]
```

[image]

We do a final tidy-up to replace the escaped semicolons with plain semicolons for storage with that list comprehension. The regex is shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820215/677173).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I prefer the APOC approach and it seems to be working for me.